# How do I dispay Rupee symbols in a TextView?

Tags: android

Can anyone please help me to identify how to insert rupee symbol in a TextView.
I have tried using \u20B9 as suggested in one of the threads, but it did not help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the font you're using doesn't have ₹?

Comment: Can you please let me know the font that I need to use? Also how do I apply it to a TextView?

Comment: try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android's system font does not support the Rupee symbol. You need to embed it in your own using font embedding.

Follow this tutorial for the font embedding:

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount